# uint32_t won't go into the struct value

Tags: c, struct

I have a structure of the following

```
struct requestPacket {

    uint32_t INDEX :4;
    uint32_t KEYSIZE :4;
    uint8_t *KEY ; // Size N*N

};
```

In which I try to add the parameters in with the following function

```
struct requestPacket* createRequest(uint32_t keySize,uint32_t index){
    printf("create packet \n");

    struct requestPacket *packet = malloc(sizeof(struct requestPacket));
    printf("KEYSIZE %d\n",keySize);

    packet->INDEX = (uint32_t) index;
    printf(" idnex %u\n", packet->INDEX);
    packet->KEY = malloc(keySize*keySize);//create the key
    for(int i = 0 ; i < keySize*keySize; i++){
        packet->KEY[i] = rand();

    }

    packet->KEYSIZE = keySize;

    printf("KEYSIZE %u\n",packet->KEYSIZE);
    fflush(stdout);
}
```

I call the function

```
struct requestPacket *packet = createRequest(keySize,128);
```

where `keySize` is an `uint32_t` retrieved with `atoi()`
I am able to get the parameter index and print a value of 12 but with `packet->KEYSIZE` the parameter seems to wrap around 128 ie when it passes 128 it does a modulo of 128.

I would like to input an value of 4 bytes into the parameter `packet->KEYSIZE` that  I can get from `atoi()` but I am unable to do so. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why are you using `malloc()` for a variable that you allocate and free in the same function and it has static size? Just use `struct requestPacket packet;`

Comment: @Barmar it was just so that I wouldn't forget to free it. I'll remove it right away

Comment: If it's a normal variable you don't need to free it.

Comment: Your function claims to return something, but returns nothing, and frees everything it allocated before doing so. Further, the `KEYSIZE` member is only 4 bits wide (as is `INDEX`). The max value it can ever hold is 15. That isn't even a byte; it's a nibble.

Comment: Anyway, the answer to your question is that you declared `INDEX` and `KEY` as 4-bit fields. They can only hold values from 0 to 15.

Comment: You shouldn't free it, you should `return packet`

Comment: You are defining both ```KEYSIZE``` and ```INDEX``` as 4 bit fields but you are trying to cast 32 bits into them

Comment: I understant my error now it ws because I mistook bit fields for byte fields. Thank you very much!

Comment: by removing the bitfields it now prints what I want it to print :)